# System.NullReferenceException when adding a value to parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

So I am trying to write a method that checks if the username the user entered exists in the MySQL database or not. However I get hit with this exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Pointing to this line of code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", usernameTextBox.Text);
```

Here is the checkusername method:

```
String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();
conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
queryStr = "";
queryStr = "SELECT count(*) FROM webappdemo.userregistration WHERE username = ?username";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", usernameTextBox.Text);
cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
if (result > 0)
{
    //username taken
    doesuserexist = true;
    LabelUsername.Text = "Username Exists";
}
else
{
    //username good
    doesuserexist = false;
    LabelUsername.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Swap `cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);` with the line above it

Comment: Wow that solved it. Thanks m8.